# Change Font Size Jquery Hightcharts

Tags: font-size, highcharts

is there any way to change font size of chart in hightcharts jquery??
i've tried the fontsize option, but it doesn't works at all..

i tried to make the legend font smaller so that it can fit to the cart with no new line created if the legend to long.
maybe anyone ever tried it??

here is my script:

```
options = {

                   chart: {

                    backgroundColor: {

                    linearGradient:[0, 0, 500, 500],

                    stops: [

                        [0, 'rgb(255,255,255)'],

                        [1, 'rgb(237,236, 250)']]},

                    type:    tGraf,

                    renderTo: contGrafik,

                    defaultSeriesType: 'column',

                    width: sWidth

                   },

                   title: {

                      text: 'Human Resources',

                      style: {

                            font: 'normal 14px Verdana, sans-serif',

                            color : 'black'

                        }

                   },

                    subtitle: {

                        text: '',

                        style: {

                            font: 'normal 11px Verdana, sans-serif',

                            color : '#000099'

                        }

                    },

                   xAxis: {

                    title: {

                        text : ''

                    },

                    labels: {

                        rotation: 0,

                        align: 'right',

                        style: {

                            font: 'normal 11px Verdana, sans-serif',

                            color : 'black'

                        }

                     },

                   },

                   yAxis: {

                        allowDecimals : false ,

                       labels: {

                        align: 'right',

                            style: {

                                font: 'normal 11px Verdana, sans-serif',

                                color : 'black'

                            }

                        },

                        gridLineColor: '#EEEFE1',

                        title: {

                            text: 'Employees',

                            style: {

                                font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif',

                                color : 'black'

                            }

                        }

                   },

                    plotOptions: {

                    column: {

                        dataLabels : {

                            enabled : true,

                            formatter: function() {

                                 return this.y;

                              }

                            },

                        cursor: 'pointer'

                        }},

                    legend: {

                        itemWidth : uLegend, 
                        style: {

                                font: 'normal 5px Verdana, sans-serif',

                                color : 'black',

                            }

                        symbolPadding: 2,

                        symbolWidth: 15,

                        backgroundColor: '#FFFF99',

                        itemStyle: {

                            cursor: 'pointer',

                            color: '#3E576F'

                        },

                        width: 600,

                        align: 'center',

                        layout: 'horizontal'},

                    tooltip: {

                      formatter: function() {

                         return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+this.y + ' Orang';

                      }

                   }

                };
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be looking for `itemStyle` option of a legend:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '8px'
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, i haven't tried that before :D

now it working perfectly XD

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the answer given by Igor is good, but if you want to change the text at every place in you graph in one shot, just open the highchart.js file and put the desired font style over there. Just providing the modification which I have done in my case:

```
style:{fontFamily:' "Exo 2", sans-serif',fontSize:"12px"},backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"
```

Here I have changed "Lucida" to "Exo 2". :)

Comment: Why just don't use `Highcharts.setOptions({ chart: { style: { fontFamily: '...' } } });` ?

Comment: My answer is for the case when you want to change the text of high-chart in every page. Then just do the changes in highchart.js file itself. No additional changes required.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sitepoint.com/auto-text-fill-resize-plugins/

check this site, 
you will find 5 ways to resize the size using the jquery, 
i have tried the first one, it already worked